# of+ how questions

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

In this sentence,

> We need to have a better understanding of how consumers view trace contamination.
> We need a better understanding of how to meet her needs".
> Ned's photography and notes bring us to a much better understanding of how it came about".

can I reduce "of"?
I mean can I rewrite as

> We need to have a better understanding how consumers view trace contamination.
> We need a better understanding how to meet her needs".
> Ned's photography and notes bring us to a much better understanding how it came about".?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be understood, but it would be a mistake. There's some confusion here, because "understanding" can be a noun or a verb. The examples you give at first all use it as a noun, and they all need "of", just as you would have a "vase **of** flowers," not a "vase flowers."

But you could get rid of the "of" if you let "understand" work as a verb:

> We need to better understand how consumers view trace contamination.